# If Statement not correctly identifying that repo file exists

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, yum

I have an if statement that is looking for the existence of a repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`:  My code is as follow:

```
OptoolsRepo='rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms'   

     if [ -e /etc/yum.repos.d/$OptoolsRepo ]
     then 
        echo " "
            echo "Your Repo For OpenStack OpTools already exists."
          else
        #       function add-repo() {
        #               reponame='rhel-7-server-rpms'
        #               url='XXXXXXX/XXX/XXX/XXXX/'
                        touch /etc/yum.repos.d/$OptoolsRepo.repo
                        echo -e "[$OptoolsRepo]\nname=$OptoolsRepo\nbaseurl=${urlOptools}\nsselverify=0\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0\nmetadata_expire=12h"  >> /etc/yum.repos.d/$OptoolsRepo.repo
        #}
     fi
```

In the `/etc/yum.repos.d/`  I see the following:

```
[root@XXXXX ~]# ls -lah /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 52K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 22 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 91 root root 8.0K Oct 19 14:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.0K Oct 21 14:09 .repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  254 Jun 29 03:59 rhel7-isv.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  269 Jun 19 10:45 rhel7-security.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  518 Oct 22 13:42 rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms
```

I'm not sure why this is occuring. Is there a syntax issue with my "if" statement? Would love help if anyone can help!

Comment: why did you put `''` around then? the general syntax for if statements is: if [ //statement ]; then

Comment: Not even `''` but backticks.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem is that the statement does not recognize that the repo file already exists.

Comment: You should be getting an error from this code snippet? Are you? If you are you should be including that in your question

Comment: I'm not getting an error because it's just appending the file that already exists. Also I've tried without backticks, I've tried with quotations, I've tried without any, not sure what my issue may be.

Comment: Sorry my question was incorrect! I didn't put 'then' that was an upload error when I was inputting the code. Imagine the statement without 'then'

Comment: @EtanReisner I didn't put the backticks there lol. That was an upload error from my question. Imagine the statement without the backticks.

Comment: I updated the question to remove the erroneous backticks from around the `then` in the `if` statement.

Comment: So the problem here was that you were testing for the wrong file because you missed the `.repo` extension on it?

Comment: @EtanReisner exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax error, the correct way is:

```
#!/bin/bash

OptoolsRepo='rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms'   

     if [ -e "/etc/yum.repos.d/"$OptoolsRepo ]; then

        echo " "
            echo "Your Repo For OpenStack OpTools already exists."
          else
        #       function add-repo() {
        #               reponame='rhel-7-server-rpms'
        #               url='XXXXXXX/XXX/XXX/XXXX/'
                        touch /etc/yum.repos.d/$OptoolsRepo.repo
                        echo -e "[$OptoolsRepo]\nname=$OptoolsRepo\nbaseurl=${urlOptools}\nsselverify=0\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0\nmetadata_expire=12h"  >> /etc/yum.repos.d/$OptoolsRepo.repo
        #}
     fi
```

Comment: Hey Douglas, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. I think you only need the semicolon whenever the then is on the same line as the statement itself.

Comment: That is true that the semicolon is only necessary when the `then` shows up on a different line, but this should fix your problem since @douglas also removed the erroneous backticks from around the `then` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Sorry my question was incorrect! I didn't put `'then'` that was an upload error when I was inputting the code. Imagine the statement without `'then'`

Comment: @user2019182 debug the script add -x in #!/bin/bash. Ex: #!/bin/bash -x

Comment: Ahhh Very Helpful. ` `+ echo ' '

+ '[' -e /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms ']'
+ touch /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms
+ echo -e '[rhel-7-server-7.0-rpms]\nname=rhel-7-server-openstack-7.0-optools-rpms\nbaseurl=XXXXX/\nsselverify=0\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0\nmetadata_expire=12h'`

Comment: I figured it out with your help. Thank you very much good sir/madam! The syntax was fine. The problem was the way I was defining my variable. It was looking for the file without the `.repo` extension.